# How to use vuejs 2 in few html pages with typescript & ASP.Net Core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, typescript, razor, vuejs2

I have an ASP.Net Core MVC with razor views that uses VueJs2 when it needs to be more complex.

I want to have a js file per view.

My folder structure is like that:

```
├ Controllers\HomeController.cs (with actions Index & Details)
├ Scripts\Home\index.ts
├ Scripts\Home\details.ts
├ Views\Home\Index.cshtml
├ Views\Home\Details.csthml
├ wwwroot\lib\vue
├ wwwroot\js\Home\index.js (generated with typescript)
├ wwwroot\js\Home\details.js (generated with typescript)
├ tsconfig.json
```

Here is my tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "outDir": "wwwroot/js",
    "rootDir": "Scripts",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es5",
      "es2015.promise"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "wwwroot/lib/vue/typings",
    "Scripts"
  ],
  "compileOnSave": true
}
```

My index.ts file

```
import Vue from 'vue'

var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        message: 'Hello Vue!'
    }
})
```

And the generated file:

```
"use strict";
var vue_1 = require("vue");
var app = new vue_1.default({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        message: 'Hello Vue!'
    }
});
//# sourceMappingURL=index.js.map
```

In my Index.cshtml I load the js file but I have this require instruction that is not working in my browsers.

How to have this js files working within a browser?

Comment: "have this require instruction that is not working in my browsers." - what error do you get?

Answer (score 0):

Note, in your **tsconfig.json**, since you did not specify a `"module"` setting, it is defaulting to `"commonjs"`, specify this or another value (see below) explicitly.

The problem here is that browsers do not widely support modules yet. Those that do have incomplete, preliminary support. In order to use modules in the browser you need a loader or a packager.

Solid options include SystemJS (optionally with jspm), RequireJS, Webpack, or Browserify.

Some notes:

In your **tsconfig.json**'s `"compilerOptions"`

Set `"module": "system"` if you go with SystemJS.

Set `"module": "amd"` and remove `"allowSyntheticDefaultImports"` if you go with RequireJS.

Set `"module": "commonjs"` if you go with Webpack.

Set `"module": "commonjs"` and remove `"allowSyntheticDefaultImports"` if you go with Browserify.